# How to pass user input to jquery .click using eventdata?

Tags: jquery, forms

Have two buttons which use jQuery's `.click` to activate a function.  The function is passed an integer parameter so currently one button passes `3` and one passes `4` to the function `sort()`.  Ideally I would like the user to input whatever integer they like and then have only one button that uses the `.click`.  The user input could be a drop down selector or manually input. This sounds like a form to me but I don't know how to bring a form and `.click` together.  I'm still a beginner on this, so maybe this is a fairly simple GET form that can work with the `.click`?

My current code includes:

```
<button class="btn btn-warning" type="submit" id="freeze3">&raquo; Random Groups 3</button>
<button class="btn btn-warning" type="submit" id="freeze4">&raquo; Random Groups 4</button>

$( "#freeze3" ).click(function() {
    if (moving == true) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        setTimeout(sort(3), 1000);
    }
    moving = false;
});

$( "#freeze4" ).click(function() {
    if (moving == true) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        setTimeout(sort(4), 1000);
    }
    moving = false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need no form, just two inputs like a `input type=number` and a `button`(which you alerady have):

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  let groupNumber = $("#groups").val();
  
  console.log("Random Group", groupNumber);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="groups">Random Groups</label>
<input type="number" id="groups">
<button>Apply</button>
```

It could be done with a `select` input as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something as basic an a regular text input, select, or numeric input. Using a plain text input you could do the following, using `this.value` to get the input the user enters:

```
$( "#myInput" ).change(function() {
    if (moving == true) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        setTimeout(sort( this.value ), 1000);
    }
    moving = false;
});
```

Of course you'd also want to do some basic validation to make sure they're entering something valid. Notice also that I'm using the change event but you could also use blur. Or you could have a text input and a button, using the button to trigger the function on click.